# Where do the local arara rules live under windows?

Tags: windows, arara

I know they go under `~/.arara` under unix platforms, but I tried having them under `%USERPROFILE%\.arara`, and they are not getting picked up.

Comment: you mean `araraconfig.yaml` ?
does `echo %USERPROFILE%` give you `C:\Users\Username` , `araraconfig.yaml` should reside there ? BTW Which version of Windows ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the preface of section 6 (“Configuration file”) and subsection 6.1 (“Search paths”) in the GREAT arara manual (I speak of version 3.0 here). You have to create a configuration file with the name “araraconfig.yaml” directly in `%UserProfile%`, and in this file you can add a path for your local rules.

`%UserProfile%` is:

- until Windows XP by default `C:\<Documents and Settings>\<username>`, where `<Documents and Settings>` is language dependent.
- since Windows Vista by default `C:\Users\<username>`. You see, the first part `Users` is valid for all languages, but Microsoft even so thought, it would be a good idea to provide in system’s own Windows Explorer only a translated folder name (e.g. here in German I can only see [`Benutzer`](http://www.dict.cc/?s=benutzer)). But on command line and in batches and cases like here for `arara` you need the correct folder name `Users` – but the best approach would consist in only using the mentioned system variable with added subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows 10 (and TeX Live 2016) and I've found them in:

```
C:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\rules
```