# Can arara rules be accessed from a portable source?

Tags: installing, arara

Sort of a continuation of this question:  [Where do the local arara rules live under windows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150617/where-do-the-local-arara-rules-live-under-windows)...

I use LaTeX on just about every computer I use, and since I am constantly bouncing between work and personal computers (windows and linux) I have to bring my TeX projects etc with me using a memory stick or dropbox.  While base installs aren't usually a problem, some programs and their corresponding customization files are missing.

So, I unzip arara into a folder in my dropbox, and configure it using the great advice here: 
[texlipse builder script configuration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60131/texlipse-builder-script-configuration) but it's not practical to use a texmf tree local to the miktex install or the user account of the current computer.  Namely, it's a little inconvenient to have to rewrite or copy rules and files every time I switch computers.

Unfortunately when I try and add a root path to the arara rules folder I end up with a `Not a TDS-compliant root directory` error.  I think this might be similar as well to this problem:  [TDS Problem - Root Direction / My Folder: C:\tex - Should work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148964/tds-problem-root-direction-my-folder-c-tex-should-work)

I have read through the documentation here:  http://tug.org/tds/tds.html
but I think `texmf/tex` isn't compatible with the folder structure of arara.

Can I do anything to add the rules folder of arara to my tex tree if it is stored on a portable media like a memory stick or a dropbox directory?

**UPDATE**

Sorry, forgot to mention that I know this worked previously...  On a windows computer with arara unziped and saved here:  `F:\Dropbox\Personal\arara` my custom arara rules were working this past summer...